# Android Fragment Tabs being created twice on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a Java veteran, but new at Android.

Anyway, the following is a block of code from my Activity.onCreate() method:

```
allContactsPage = new AllContactsPage();
allGroupsPage = new AllGroupsPage();

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.contactsTabsViewPager);
ContactsTabsPagerAdapter tabsAdapter = new ContactsTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), allContactsPage, allGroupsPage);
viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactsActivityTabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

contactsService.loadAllContacts(this);
```

The allContactsPage and allGroupsPage are fragments. I add them to the TabLayout using a ViewPager and a FragmentPageAdapter (ContactsTabsPagerAdapter).

After all this, I call loadAllContacts(this) on my service. "this" is passed as a callback, so when it's done it calls back into the activity, which updates both fragments with the data they should display (both fragments are instance variables).

My problem is that, on rotation, two of each fragment is created. One version is displayed in the UI, another version is called by the callback. So the one that displays in the UI is blank, and never gets the data.

I've seen a bunch of posts about this issue, but I haven't seen how to perfectly handle it with the fragments managed by a ViewPager/FragmentPagerAdapter. I just want to know how to ensure that I have the correct fragment reference to pass the data to upon rotation.

Once I get that resolved, I'm probably going to dive into avoiding loading the data on rotation, but I've already figured out how to do that. Just need to figure out how to make it display properly.

Comment: more code needed for investigation... especially `Activity` and `Fragment`s lifecycle methods and calls... probably your `Fragment`s are added to backstack and recreated on rotation (blind shot)

Comment: Have you try to add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
     android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />
```

OR

```
<activity
     android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your Fragment instantiation into your `ContactsTabPagerAdapter`.  Something like

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0: return new AllContactsPage();
        case 1: return new AllGroupsPage();
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

The PagerAdapter contains logic for reusing fragments, and should handle this for you.  See https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#L90